# Which is the type of (flip .)?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

I'm trying to understand why the type of:

`(flip .) is: (a -> a1 -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> a1 -> c`

First of all, the type of:

`flip: is (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`
`(.):  is (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

I will rename the variables to be more clear in my explanation, so the types:

`flip: is (ax -> bx -> cx) -> bx -> ax -> cx`
`(.): is (by -> cy) -> (ay -> by) -> ay -> cy`

Then I try substituing like this:

`ax = (by -> cy)`
`bx = (ay -> by)`
`cx = ay -> cy`

So the resulting type is: (ay -> by) (by -> cy) -> ay -> cy, which is different with the correct result.

Any help?

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Comment: You do realize that `(flip .)` and `flip (.)` mean very different things?

Comment: No, I'm not sure of the difference between the types and the effect of applying one or the other.

Comment: `(flip .)` is `(.) flip`, just like `(2+)` is `(+) 2`.

Comment: In what you wrote, `flip .`, the `flip` value is an argument to the function named `.`.  But you solved the type for if the `.` value were an argument to the function `flip` (which you can do by writing `flip (.)`).

Comment: @ Thomas M. DuBuisson What you are saying is that I resolved the type for flip (.) instead of for (flip .)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(flip .)` is `(.) flip`, so:

- `(.) :: (bx -> cx) -> (ax -> bx) -> ax -> cx`
- `flip :: (ay -> by -> cy) -> by -> ay -> cy`
- In `(.) flip`,

  - `bx` is `ay -> by -> cy`
  - `cx` is `by -> ay -> cy`
  - so it’s all `(ax -> (ay -> by -> cy)) -> ax -> (by -> ay -> cy)`,
    which is just `(ax -> ay -> by -> cy) -> ax -> by -> ay -> cy`,
    which matches up with `(flip .) :: (a -> a1 -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> a1 -> c`.